# Computing age in days with a graphical tool in Java

Tags: java, swing, gui

I was in the mood for doing some GUI coding, and eventually I came with this simple program: you enter a date, press the button, and the program tells you temporal difference in days between the input date and current date.

```
package net.coderodde.gui.date;

import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.Toolkit;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.Date;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JComboBox;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.JSlider;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.event.ChangeEvent;
import javax.swing.event.ChangeListener;

public class DaysCounter implements ChangeListener, ActionListener {

    /**
     * The actual frame of this program.
     */
    private final JFrame frame;

    /**
     * The label displaying the currently selected day of month.
     */
    private final JLabel dayLabel;

    /**
     * The slider for choosing the day of month.
     */
    private final JSlider daySlider;

    /**
     * The combo box for choosing the month.
     */
    private final JComboBox monthComboBox;

    /**
     * The text field for inputting the year.
     */
    private final JTextField yearTextField;

    /**
     * The button for initiating the age calculation.
     */
    private final JButton computeButton;

    /**
     * Constructs the graphical user interface.
     */
    public DaysCounter() {
        // Construct components:
        this.frame = new JFrame("Age in days");
        this.dayLabel = new JLabel("16");
        this.daySlider = new JSlider(1, 31, 16);

        String[] months = new String[] {
            "January",
            "February",
            "March",
            "April",
            "May",
            "June",
            "Jule",
            "August",
            "September",
            "October",
            "November",
            "December",
        };

        this.monthComboBox = new JComboBox(months);
        this.yearTextField = new JTextField("1980");
        this.computeButton = new JButton("Compute");

        // Add listeners:
        daySlider.addChangeListener(this);
        computeButton.addActionListener(this);

        // Align the selected day field horizontally.
        dayLabel.setHorizontalAlignment(JLabel.CENTER);

        // Add the components to the frame.
        frame.getContentPane().setLayout(new GridLayout(5, 1));
        frame.getContentPane().add(dayLabel);
        frame.getContentPane().add(daySlider);
        frame.getContentPane().add(monthComboBox);
        frame.getContentPane().add(yearTextField);
        frame.getContentPane().add(computeButton);

        frame.pack();

        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setResizable(false);

        // Center out the frame.
        Dimension dim = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize();

        frame.setLocation((dim.width - frame.getWidth()) / 2,
                          (dim.height - frame.getHeight()) / 2);

        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(final String... args) {
        javax.swing.SwingUtilities.invokeLater(() -> {
            new DaysCounter();
        });
    }

    /**
     * Change the current day of month.
     * 
     * @param e the event object.
     */
    @Override
    public void stateChanged(ChangeEvent e) {
        dayLabel.setText("" + ((JSlider) daySlider).getValue());
    }

    /**
     * Initiates the age calculation.
     * 
     * @param e the button press event, ignored.
     */
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        Calendar start = Calendar.getInstance();
        Calendar end = Calendar.getInstance();

        int year;

        try {
            year = Integer.parseInt(yearTextField.getText());
        } catch (NumberFormatException ex) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(
                    frame, 
                    "Bad year: " + yearTextField.getText(), 
                    "Error",
                    JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);

            return;
        }

        start.set(year,
                  monthComboBox.getSelectedIndex(),
                  daySlider.getValue());

        if (!isValidDate(start)) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,
                                         "The input date is invalid!", 
                                         "Error", 
                                         JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
            return;
        }

        Date startDate = start.getTime();
        Date endDate = end.getTime();

        long startTime = startDate.getTime();
        long endTime = endDate.getTime();

        long days = (endTime - startTime) / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24);

        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(
                frame, 
                "You are " + days + " day" + (days == 1 ? "" : "s") + " old.", 
                "", 
                JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
    }

    /**
     * Checks the validity of the input date.
     * 
     * @param  c the input date.
     * @return {@code true} only if the input date is valid.
     */
    private boolean isValidDate(Calendar c) {
        c.setLenient(false);

        try {
            c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
            c.get(Calendar.MONTH);
            c.get(Calendar.YEAR);
            return true;
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

So, what do you think?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Comments and naming

I'd same some of your comments identifying the fields are rather inane - I can guess that `private final JFrame frame;` is in fact "the actual frame of this program."  By contrast, some of the other comments are pretty useful, but more because the name of the field isn't as descriptive as possible - its almost always better to have your code be self explanatory (through clear formatting and logic, as well as good names) than to comment and explain it.  For example `dayLabel` could probably be more clearly named as `currentSelectedDayLabel` and then remove the comment.

Likewise, anyone who is even a little familiar with Java (and even people who aren't) can guess/know that the lines

```
chooseDaySlider.addChangeListener(this);
computeAgeButton.addActionListener(this);
```

are adding listeners without a comment explaining that.

### Lambda function

In your main function you use a lambda, which is fine, but you could do it even more cleanly with a [method reference](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/methodreferences.html).

```
public static void main(final String... args) {
    javax.swing.SwingUtilities.invokeLater(DaysCounter::new);
}
```

### Casting

You unnecessarily cast your `JSlider` to a... `JSlider`.  Just call `getValue()` directly.

```
@Override
public void stateChanged(ChangeEvent e) {
    currentSelectedDayLabel.setText("" + chooseDaySlider.getValue());
}
```

### actionPerformed

This part seems pretty good, however I'd say you could refactor the distinct sections into their own methods.  Furthermore, the entire "days alive" calculation can be simplified.  It's also a little magic number-y, but I'd say these are okay because they make sense - 1000 ms, 60 s, 60 m, 24 hr.  If you wanted to make these more explicit you could, but in this case I think they would just make it harder to understand.

```
/**
 * Initiates the age calculation.
 *
 * @param e the button press event, ignored.
 */
@Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    Calendar start = Calendar.getInstance();
    Calendar end = Calendar.getInstance();

    int year = getYear();

    if (year == -1) return;

    start.set(year,
            monthComboBox.getSelectedIndex(),
            chooseDaySlider.getValue());

    if (!isValidDate(start)) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,
                "The input date is invalid!",
                "Error",
                JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
        return;
    }

    long days = calculateNumDaysAlive(start.getTime(), end.getTime());

    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(
            frame,
            "You are " + days + " day" + (days == 1 ? "" : "s") + " old.",
            "",
            JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
}

/**
 * Gets the numeric year
 *
 * @return the year if it can be determined, otherwise -1.
 */
private int getYear() {
    try {
        return Integer.parseInt(yearTextField.getText());
    } catch (NumberFormatException ex) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(
                frame,
                "Bad year: " + yearTextField.getText(),
                "Error",
                JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
        return -1;
    }
}
```

### Tests

It wouldn't hurt to have some tests either, although given the relative simplicity of the calculations here it probably isn't that big of a deal.

### Everything

Here is how I adapted your code in total.

```
package net.coderodde.gui.date;

import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.Toolkit;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.Date;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JComboBox;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.JSlider;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.event.ChangeEvent;
import javax.swing.event.ChangeListener;

public class DaysCounter implements ChangeListener, ActionListener {

    private final JFrame frame;
    private final JLabel currentSelectedDayLabel;
    private final JSlider chooseDaySlider;
    private final JComboBox monthComboBox;
    private final JTextField yearTextField;
    private final JButton computeAgeButton;

    public DaysCounter() {
        this.frame = new JFrame("Age in days");
        this.currentSelectedDayLabel = new JLabel("16");
        this.chooseDaySlider = new JSlider(1, 31, 16);

        String[] months = new String[] {
                "January",
                "February",
                "March",
                "April",
                "May",
                "June",
                "Jule",
                "August",
                "September",
                "October",
                "November",
                "December",
        };

        this.monthComboBox = new JComboBox(months);
        this.yearTextField = new JTextField("1980");
        this.computeAgeButton = new JButton("Compute");

        chooseDaySlider.addChangeListener(this);
        computeAgeButton.addActionListener(this);

        currentSelectedDayLabel.setHorizontalAlignment(JLabel.CENTER);

        frame.getContentPane().setLayout(new GridLayout(5, 1));
        frame.getContentPane().add(currentSelectedDayLabel);
        frame.getContentPane().add(chooseDaySlider);
        frame.getContentPane().add(monthComboBox);
        frame.getContentPane().add(yearTextField);
        frame.getContentPane().add(computeAgeButton);

        frame.pack();

        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setResizable(false);

        // Center out the frame.
        Dimension dim = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize();

        frame.setLocation((dim.width - frame.getWidth()) / 2,
                (dim.height - frame.getHeight()) / 2);

        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(final String... args) {
        javax.swing.SwingUtilities.invokeLater(DaysCounter::new);
    }

    /**
     * Change the current day of month.
     *
     * @param e the event object.
     */
    @Override
    public void stateChanged(ChangeEvent e) {
        currentSelectedDayLabel.setText("" + chooseDaySlider.getValue());
    }

    /**
     * Initiates the age calculation.
     *
     * @param e the button press event, ignored.
     */
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        Calendar start = Calendar.getInstance();
        Calendar end = Calendar.getInstance();

        int year = getYear();

        if (year == -1) return;

        start.set(year,
                monthComboBox.getSelectedIndex(),
                chooseDaySlider.getValue());

        if (!isValidDate(start)) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,
                    "The input date is invalid!",
                    "Error",
                    JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
            return;
        }

        long days = calculateNumDaysAlive(start.getTime(), end.getTime());

        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(
                frame,
                "You are " + days + " day" + (days == 1 ? "" : "s") + " old.",
                "",
                JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
    }

    /**
     * Gets the numeric year
     *
     * @return the year if it can be determined, otherwise -1.
     */
    private int getYear() {
        try {
            return Integer.parseInt(yearTextField.getText());
        } catch (NumberFormatException ex) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(
                    frame,
                    "Bad year: " + yearTextField.getText(),
                    "Error",
                    JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
            return -1;
        }
    }

    /**
     * Calculates the number of days between two dates.
     *
     * @param start the staring date.
     * @param end the ending date.
     * @return the number of days between the two dates.
     */
    private long calculateNumDaysAlive(Date start, Date end) {
        return (end.getTime() - start.getTime()) / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24);
    }

    /**
     * Checks the validity of the input date.
     *
     * @param  c the input date.
     * @return {@code true} only if the input date is valid.
     */
    private boolean isValidDate(Calendar c) {
        c.setLenient(false);

        try {
            c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
            c.get(Calendar.MONTH);
            c.get(Calendar.YEAR);
            return true;
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

- Instead of:

  ```
  currentSelectedDayLabel.setText("" + chooseDaySlider.getValue());
  ```

  I'd use:

  ```
  currentSelectedDayLabel.setText(Integer.toString(chooseDaySlider.getValue()));
  ```

  This creates just one `String` object (the result) instead of two (the empty and the resulting) and a `StringBuilder` object to append them.

  See also [the accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3930249/1744774) of *Java int to String - Integer.toString(i) vs new Integer(i).toString()*.
- I'd use:

  ```
  String.format("You are %d%s old.", days, days == 1 ? "" : "s")
  ```

  instead of string concatenation:

  ```
  "You are " + days + " day" + (days == 1 ? "" : "s") + " old."
  ```

  This shows the structure of the resulting string and the parameter types at a glance.